# How to observe the number of objects in a table view?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, key-value-observing

I need to observe the number of objects in a table view and display it with a badge. I use Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController in the project. Should I use KVO or other mechanisms?

Comment: That's what KVO is for.

Comment: @rocky, Which property of which object should I observe?

Answer (score 1):

YES, of course you can use `KVO` to observe the number of the objects.

But , if the models (assume the number of the objects change in this part) code is your coding or you can modify the models code. I think you should better use `NSNotifaction` or `delegate` or `block` , it is just a callback when you change the objects count.

`KVO` is better to observer the var which in the standard library or in the class which you cannot modify